# Should an Activity always have a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm writing an android application. 
I've got a MainActivity. 
The MainActivity has Viewpager which have three Fragments.
I also have another activity named CreateStudyActivity. 
This class creates an Object and returns it to the MainActivty. There is no need to change the fragment and I dont want to share the fragment to other Activities.

Now my Question. Is it a good practice to create for every Activity a Fragment. or is it an overkill?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it totally depends on your requirement.

Comment: The `Fragment` represents a portion of an `Activity`, you can use an `Activity` without `Fragment`. You can also use *many* `Fragment`s inside one `Activity`. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: A few years ago, Fragments didn't even exist. All was done with Activities. So, no, Fragments aren't **necessary**. But I'd go for **1** only Activity (or the least possible) and use as many Fragments you need.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, could you accept it? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not always.  There's 2 main reasons to use fragment

1)If you plan on reusing the same UI and controller code in different locations (either different activities or rearranging in different orientations).

2)If you want tighter control over the backstack.

If neither of those are true fragments don't really provide much value to you.  For example, a simple calculator app wouldn't have any need to use a fragment.  Use it if it makes sense, skip them if they don't.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't change screen inside `activity` with different screen, `activity` is enough. Here you say you have `ViewPager` inside `activity` and it has 3 `fragments`, which means you change from one fragment(screen) to another `fragment`(screen) by swiping... so you definitely use `fragments` in order to inflate 3 different screens inside `activity`.

If one page(screen) is enough, only `activity` itself is enough and why would you use `ViewPager` and 3 `fragments`

Answer (score 1):

I would say to not use `Fragments` unless you need to use them - for example, if you want an `Activity` that would allow you to swipe left/right to see different portions of the screen, you would use `ViewPager` and `Fragment`s. And `Fragment`s are exactly that - portions of the main screen. If you do not need a swipe feature or parts of the `Activity` to change without actually changing `Activity`, then don't use `Fragments`, to answer your question.

You can read more about building a dynamic UI with fragments on [the Android developer website](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html).